# Use of CASE statement in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables:

```
TASK (id_task (PRIMARY KEY), name) 
PROJECT (id_project (PRIMARY KEY), name)
PROJECT_HAS_TASK (id_project, task_id)
```

`PROJECT_HAS_TASK` is the (n,m) relation between `PROJECT` and `TASK`.

I'd like to return all the `TASK` records and a boolean value indicating if the `task_id` also exists in `PROJECT_HAS_TASK`. Is that possible to do with a SQL query? Or should I use a stored procedure?

EDIT :
Yes it is possible to do it with a SQL query. Thanks to both a1ex07 and bummi's help I ended up with this solution :

```
SELECT a.id_task,  
Case WHEN b.id_task IS NULL then 0 else 1 end as HasProject 
from TASK a
LEFT join (SELECT DISTINCT id_task FROM PROJECT_HAS_TASK)b on (a.id_task = b.id_task);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to check if there is any project that has task, use something like

```
SELECT a.id_task,  
Case WHEN b.id_task IS NULL then 0 else 1 end as HasProject 
from TASK a
LEFT join (SELECT DISTINCT id_task FROM PROJECT_HAS_TASK)b on (a.id_task = b.id_task)
;
-- if you need number of tasks for a project
Select  a.id_task,
COUNT(b.id_project) as num_projects
from TASK a
LEFT join PROJECT_HAS_TASK b on a.id_task = b.id_task
GROUP BY a.id_task;
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! Your help is much appreciated ! That works perfectly and It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution will cause performance problems if there will be larger number of records as there will be not index used in this JOIN statement:

```
LEFT join (SELECT DISTINCT id_task FROM PROJECT_HAS_TASK)b on (a.id_task = b.id_task);
```

Probably you should try something using the EXISTS statement like this

```
SELECT `TASK`.`id_task`,  
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `PROJECT_HAS_TASK` 
                  WHERE `TASK`.`id_task` = `PROJECT_HAS_TASK`.`id_task`) 
  THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END as HasProject 
FROM `TASK`;
```

or the simplified (for MySQL only):

```
SELECT t.id_task,  
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PROJECT_HAS_TASK AS pt 
               WHERE t.id_task = pt.id_task) 
         AS HasProject 
FROM TASK AS t;
```

Comment: Assuming `PROJECT_HAS_TASK` has foreign key to `task` it's impossible (for mysql innodb) not to have index on `PROJECT_HAS_TASK.id_task`. `SELECT DISTINCT id_task FROM PROJECT_HAS_TASK` must scan index, not table unless: 1 serious bug in optimizer; 2 id_task is a leading column in `PROJECT_HAS_TASK` primary key, so index scan is the same as table scan. To summarize : I'm not trying to say that your approach is worse (performance-wise) than mine; I guess they should generate the same execution plan

Comment: @a1ex07
It will use index on (SELECT DISTINCT id_task FROM PROJECT_HAS_TASK) but will not use index on the join statement. Try building those tables and checking EXPLAIN on both statements yours will require three operations and on one there will be no index used.

Comment: Test with empty/few records table doesn't prove or refute anything. Until the table grows up to certain limit, full scan will be the most efficient way...

Comment: @a1ex07 It proves that "Your solution may cause performance problems if there will be larger number of records"

Comment: I guess "may cause performance problems" can be applicable to any solution :) . Especially "may"...

Comment: @a1ex07
I used 'may' because you need larger number of record to see performance issues. Your query *will* at the certain point cause performance problems but it may work depending on the use case. With 10,000 projects and 500,000 tasks your query is unusable my is taking 0.05s With 1,000 projects and 5,000 tasks your query is taking 0.9s mine 0.02s. Instead of defending your solution because it is yours try using this forum to learn something new.